# Fish how to prevent recursive function calls

Tags: fish

How can I prevent recursive function calls on fish functions when overriding a default binary with a function that has the same name ?

eg.

```sh
# Override 'ls'
function ls
    if [ my_special_condition ]
        * Do special stuff *
    else  # Call regular ls
        ls $argv
    end    
end
```

Obsiously the above code ends up in a resursive loop without calling the actual 'ls' binary.
Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to replace the `ls` function while also being able to call the original. You can do that by copying the function via `functions -c`:

```
functions -c ls orig_ls # copies ls to orig_ls
function ls
    if [ my_special_condition ]
        * Do special stuff *
    else  # Call original ls
        orig_ls $argv
    end    
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Within the function, use [the `command` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/command.html)

```
function ls
    command ls $argv
end
```

Comment: I was hoping a way to still keep the default fish version of the command (syntax highlight etc), but this is also working. Thanks !